# Two hidden layers with different neoron numbers each layer in neural network diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-node

I am trying with following code. I want to replace Hidden layer 2
with **9 nodes**. And want to add ***text1, text2, and text3*** like the following figure. And Finally, I want to replace **`Input #1 to Input #9` with `Clump Thickness, Uniformity of Cell Size, Uniformity of Cell Shape, Marginal Adhesion, Single Epithelial Cell Size, Bare Nuclei, Bland Chromatin, Normal Nuclei, Mitoses.`** Please need help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{3.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   shorten >=1pt,->,
   draw=black!50,
    node distance=\layersep,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,9}{
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y cm) {};  
     }


    % set number of hidden layers
    \newcommand\Nhidden{2}
    \newcommand\Node{13}
    \newcommand\Nod{9}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {

        \foreach \y in {1,...,\Node} {
          \path[yshift=1.80cm]
              node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y cm) {};
           }

    \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm] (hl\N) {Hidden layer \N};
    }

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Benin/Malignant}, right of=H\Nhidden-6] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,9}{
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,13}{
            \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
         }
    }
    % connect all hidden stuff
    \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
       \foreach \source in {1,...,13}
           \foreach \dest in {1,...,13}
               \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,13}
        \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers

    \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

[image: Want to Modify this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\def\layersep{3.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   shorten >=1pt,->,
   draw=black!50,
    node distance=\layersep,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name  [count=\y] in 
    {Clump Thickness, Uniformity of Cell Size, Uniformity of Cell Shape, Marginal Adhesion, Single Epithelial Cell Size, Bare Nuclei, Bland Chromatin, Normal Nuclei, Mitoses}
     {   \node[input neuron, pin=left:\name] (I-\y) at (0,-\y cm) {};  
     }


    % set number of hidden layers
    \newcommand\Nhidden{2}
    \newcommand\NodOne{13}
    \newcommand\NodTwo{9}
    \newcommand\Nod{9}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
%    \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {

     \foreach \y in {1,...,\NodOne} {
          \path[yshift=1.80cm]
              node[hidden neuron] (H1-\y) at (1*\layersep,-\y cm) {};
              }
    \node[annot,above of=H1-1, node distance=1cm] (hl1) {Hidden layer 1};
     \foreach \y in {1,...,\NodTwo} {
          \path[yshift=0cm]
              node[hidden neuron] (H2-\y) at (2*\layersep,-\y cm) {};            
           }
    \node[annot,above of=H2-1, node distance=1cm] (hl2) {Hidden layer 2};          

%    }

    \node[below=0.5cm of H1-\NodOne] (text1) {text 1};
    \node at (text1 -| H2-1) (text2) {text 2};

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Benin/Malignant}, right of=H\Nhidden-5] (O) {};

    \node at (text1 -| O) (text3) {text 3};
    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,9}{
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,\NodOne}{
            \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
         }
    }
    % connect all hidden stuff
    \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
       \foreach \source in {1,...,\NodOne}
           \foreach \dest in {1,...,\NodTwo}
               \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,\NodTwo}
        \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers

    \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, How to replace 13 nodes of Hidden Layer 2 with 9 nodes?

Comment: Sir, Please read the description of this question. How to do replace 13 nodes of Hidden Layer 2 with 9 nodes?

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque I updated my answer. Please disclose the source of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have update to do automatic layers.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=1pt,->,
    draw=black!50,
    node distance=\layersep,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=yellow!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
]
    % set number of hidden layers, input and output name
    \csdef{N-HiddenL}{4}
    \csdef{N-Input-yshift}{0.5cm}
    \csdef{N-L1}{10}
    \csdef{N-L1-yshift}{1.8cm}
    \csdef{N-L1-annot}{1cm}
    \csdef{N-L2}{8}
    \csdef{N-L2-yshift}{1.30cm}
    \csdef{N-L2-annot}{1cm}
    \csdef{N-L3}{4}
    \csdef{N-L3-yshift}{1.30cm}
    \csdef{N-L3-annot}{1cm}
    \csdef{N-L4}{4}
    \csdef{N-L4-yshift}{1.30cm}
    \csdef{N-L4-annot}{1cm}
    \csdef{N-Output-yshift}{0.5cm}
    \newcommand\InputList{x\textsubscript{1}, x\textsubscript{2}, x\textsubscript{3}}
    \newcommand\HiddenList{Camada oculta \i}
    \newcommand\OutputList{y\textsubscript{1}, y\textsubscript{2}, y\textsubscript{3}}

    % draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name [count=\i] in \InputList
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:\name, yshift=(\csuse{N-Input-yshift})] (I-\i) at (0,-\i cm) {};
    \cslet{N-Input}{\i}

    % draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\csuse{N-HiddenL}}
    {
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\csuse{N-L\i}} {
            \path[yshift=(\csuse{N-L\i-yshift})]
                node[hidden neuron] (H\i-\j) at (\i*\layersep,-\j cm) {};
        }
        \node[annot,above of=H\i-1, node distance=(\csuse{N-L\i-annot})] (hl\i) {\HiddenList};
    }

    % draw the output layer node
    \foreach \name [count=\i] in \OutputList
        \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:\name}, right of=H\csuse{N-HiddenL}-1, yshift=(\csuse{N-Output-yshift} - \i cm)] (O-\i) {};
    \cslet{N-Output}{\i}

    % annotate below the layers (draw text)
    \foreach \name [count=\i] in
    {test 1, test 2, text 3, text 4}
    {
        \ifnum \i=1
            \node[below=0.5cm of H1-\csuse{N-L1}] (text1) {\name};
        \else
            \node at (text1 -| H\i-1) (text\i) {\name};
        \fi
    }
    \node at (text1 -| O-1) (textO) {text out {\number\numexpr \csuse{N-HiddenL}+1}};

    % connect every node in the input layer with every node in the hidden layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,\csuse{N-Input}}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,\csuse{N-L1}}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);

    % connect all hidden stuff
    \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\csuse{N-HiddenL}}
        \foreach \source in {1,...,\csuse{N-L\lastN}}
            \foreach \dest in {1,...,\csuse{N-L\N}}
                \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);

    % connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,\csuse{N-L\csuse{N-HiddenL}}}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,\csuse{N-Output}}
            \path (H\csuse{N-HiddenL}-\source) edge (O-\dest);

    % annotate the layers
    \node[annot,left of=hl1, yshift=-1cm] {Camada de entrada};
    \node[annot,right of=hl\csuse{N-HiddenL}, yshift=-0.5cm] {Camada de saída};
\end{tikzpicture}
```